# python/ websocket implementation of sending messages to the client that keeps the socket open

Tags: python, websocket

Help me figure out how to implement it correctly.
The bottom line: The client is charging stations that connect, open a socket and send messages to the server and receive responses.
Server - listens to the port, sees the connected station, receives messages and sends responses to them.
Question: When the client connects and sends headers, I can send a message to the client. But I need to periodically send messages to the client that keeps the socket open, I don't understand how to implement this. Can someone tell me?

sample sending code:

```
charge_point_id = path.strip('/')
    cp = client_main(charge_point_id, websocket)
    logging.info(charge_point_id)
    print(charge_point_id)
    print(path)
    await websocket.send(json.dumps([2,"222", "GetLocalListVersion", {}]))
    await cp.start()
```

example of receiving a message from a client:

```
class client_main(cp):

        errors = False
            
        if not errors:
            
                        
            @on('BootNotification')
            def on_boot_notitication(self,    charge_point_vendor, charge_point_model,charge_point_serial_number,firmware_version, 
                                     meter_type, **kwargs):
               return call_result.BootNotificationPayload(
                    status="Accepted",
                    current_time=date_str.replace('+00:00','Z'),
                    interval=60
                )
```

---

in this case, the charging station according to the ocpp protocol opens the connection and keeps it open, it should be possible to somehow write to him

---

how do i send a message to the client? My example:

> ```
>   @on('Heartbeat')
>     def on_getlocallistversion(self):
>     await self.route_message(json.dumps([2,"222","GetLocalListVersion",{}]))
>     def on_hearbeat(self):
>         return call_result.HeartbeatPayload(
>                     current_time=datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')+"Z"
>        )
> ```

I get an error:

> await self.route_message(json.dumps([2,"222",
> "GetLocalListVersion",{}]))

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible to do. You can send a message only when the client is connected.